# Localize metadata app name on app store

Tags: iphone, localization, app-store

I am trying to localize my iphone app in Greek language. I go to the developers portal (Manage localizations) to add my new localized language but i notice that the Greek language is not listed! Many other languages are not listed as well. Check the image below to see what i mean.

http://poemsofloveapp.com/greek_loc.png

How am i supposed to add a greek name on the app store for my app?
Do i have to submit a new app?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that it is not possible because apple does not provide metadata localization options for the greek language. I asked other greek developers that had the same problem. Thank you all!